# Probability with maximum of Brownian Motion

Tags: probability, brownian-motion

Calculate this probability:
$$
P(\max_{0\leq t \leq T}B(t)>x | \min_{0\leq t \leq T}B(t)>0) = ?
$$

My attempt of solution:

$$
P(\max_{0\leq t \leq T}B(t)>x | \min_{0\leq t \leq T}B(t)>0) = 
\frac{P(\max_{0\leq t \leq T}B(t)>x \wedge \min_{0\leq t \leq T}B(t)>0)}{ P(\min_{0\leq t \leq T}B(t)>0)}
$$

Now I use the fact: 
$$
\min_{0\leq t \leq T}B(t) \stackrel{\text{d}}{=} -\max_{0\leq t \leq T}(-B(t))
$$
and I have:
$$
P(\max_{0\leq t \leq T}B(t)>x | \min_{0\leq t \leq T}B(t)>0) = 
\frac{P(\max_{0\leq t \leq T}B(t)>x \wedge -\max_{0\leq t \leq T}(-B(t))>0)}{ P(\min_{0\leq t \leq T}B(t)>0)} = 
\frac{P(\max_{0\leq t \leq T}B(t)>x \wedge \max_{0\leq t \leq T}(-B(t))<0)}{ P(\min_{0\leq t \leq T}B(t)>0)}
$$

I don't know what I can do next?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if my attempt is correct, I am learning this as well.

Assume we get $\min B(t)$ at point $a$, get $\max B(t)$ at point $b$.
$$\min B(t)=B(a), \max B(t)=B(b)$$

Rewrite your problem:
$$\frac{P[B(b)>x \cap B(a)>0 ]}{P[B(a)>0]}$$
Consider inequality here: If we have $B(b)-B(a)>x$ and $B(a)>0$, we can imply $B(b)>x$, so I am trying to substitute $B(b)>x$ with $B(b)-B(a)>x$

Hence we have

$$\frac{P[(B(b)-B(a))>x \cap B(a)>0 ]}{P[B(a)>0]}$$

Since $B(b)-B(a)=B(|b-a|)$ is independent of $B(a)$, we just need to calculate $$P[(B(|b-a|))>x]$$
That is,
$$P[(N(0,|b-a|)>x]$$

Comment: I think that transition from equation: $ \frac{P(B(b)>x \cap B(a)>0 )}{P(B(a) > 0)} $ to equation $ \frac{P(B(b)-B(a)>x \cap B(a)>0) }{P(B(a) > 0)} $ is not correct. Consider $B(b) = x+1$ and $B(a) = 2$